# Why doesn't this method with a sql update query work well?

Tags: java, sql, sql-server

I'm calling a stored procedure to update one row of a table through a java method but doesn't work right.

The method in Java that call this stored procedure I send two parameters (id of row and the new content), and the procedure updates two columns (one with the content of the parameter and the other one is a number) but somehow only updates the column of the number and the other didn't change.

If I execute the Stored Procedure on SQL Server works right and updates the two columns of the row.

I printed the value before call the stored procedure and the variables contains the correct value

This is the content of the stored procedure that I use:

```sql
UPDATE table
SET  content = @content, number=1
WHERE id = @id

select 1
```

If the stored procedure executes right I return the number 1

This is the code in java that I used to call the stored procedure

```java
Connection con;
CallableStatement cstmt;
try{
cstmt = con.prepareCall("CALL SP001(?,?)");
cstmt.setString (1, id);                          
cstmt.setString (2, content);
cstmt.executeUpdate();           
cstmt.close();   
}
catch(Exception e){
}
```

I don't know why this happens, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please provide the according java code you are using.

Comment: My guess is you are passing in the current value of the row in your variable.

Comment: @Arnaud I just added a part of the code.

Comment: @SeanLange But if I manually execute the stored procedure, it uses the value that I send it by the parameters

Comment: Why do you have an empty catch? That is an antipattern I call try/squelch. And what do you use to populate the content variable? This really boils down to basic debugging skills. Put in a break point and evaluate your variables at run time. I suspect you will have aha / OMG type of moment.